# PHP/MySQL pattern to order posts?

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, design-patterns

I have single table where i put all the content. Each row is one post. I want to be able to manipulate order of posts so that i can push some of those to the top or bottom...

Also, each post belongs to certain category. (i believe that that additional parameter makes difference when ordering posts within certain category)

Please, give me some hints/code patterns how would you do it?

p.s. i don't want to add new tables, make more relations, i want it as simple as possible...

Comment: Does `SELECT ... ORDER BY (desired order)` not suit you? If not, why not?

Comment: i have also dates (updated and inserted), category_id but i want to be able to change order of posts manually, to push some of them to the top or push them down...

Comment: i was looking for patter how to design database so that i can easily change order of posts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would personally accomplish this by adding a sort_index field to the table with a default value of something like 100.  You can then push posts down by decreasing their sort order, or push them to the top by increasing it.  By starting with a specific number, you are establishing a baseline for default sorting of posts.

```
SELECT * FROM `posts` ORDER BY sort_index DESC, date_posted DESC
```

This would use ensure posts with the same sort index get a secondary sorting based on the date they were posted.

It also allows you to then easily automate making the posts fall down in the rankings over time with a small script setup as a cron to decrease the sort index of posts every so often until they hit the default value.

Comment: It was very simple, works fine but unfortunately it's not sufficient. I'll have to find out something more sophisticated.

Comment: What exactly are you looking to do?  Your original post was a bit vague, so I was kind of guessing at what you were looking for.

Comment: As i said. I want to be able to change order of posts. Sometimes journalists publish 3-4 posts but they are not satisfied with order they are shown on the page so they want to change order. Also, articles can be within different categories which makes things bit tricky since it requires "order" to be on the level of group. Jet if you change category for certain article, you loose order index etc..

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a table with the following columns:

- id
- post
- category

You can add a new integer column called rank.  Using the new rank column you can order your posts like this:

```
SELECT `post` from tblPosts order by category, rank;
```

Now you can order your posts by assigning a rank to them.  In the above example smaller numbers will be listed at the top and larger ones at the bottom.

Comment: also interesting one.. thank you, if anyone have some other clue.. go shoot